# How to add custom SheetDataWriter on Apache poi SXSSFWorkbook?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I just want to use my own SheetDataWriter to overwrite below method

```
    /**
 * Override this to translate (such as decrypt or expand) the file input stream
 * as it is being read from disk.
 * The default behavior is to to pass the stream through unmodified.
 *
 * @param fis  the stream to decorate
 * @return a decorated stream
 * @throws IOException
 * @see #decorateOutputStream(FileOutputStream)
 */
protected InputStream decorateInputStream(FileInputStream fis) throws IOException {
    return fis;
}
```

cause I want to replace this method when set compress : true

```
@Override
//GZIPInputStream default cache byte size is 512b
protected InputStream decorateInputStream(FileInputStream fis) throws IOException {
    return new GZIPInputStream(fis);
}
```

why I want to replace this? Because I want to find out whether cache size is the main reason to slow down the write speed from poi-sxssf-sheet???.gz to poi-sxssf-template???.xlsx on **high concurrence (apache jmeter : 50 users, 6 loop, ramup 20)**.
But the question is how to use my own SheetDataWriter when init SXSSFWorkbook ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to override methods in `Java`? This seems to be a very basic question.

You could have your own `SXSSFWorkbook` class which extends default `SXSSFWorkbook` and overrides `protected SheetDataWriter createSheetDataWriter()`. There, if  is compressed temp files, you could return a extended `GZIPSheetDataWriter` which overrides `protected InputStream decorateInputStream(FileInputStream fis)`.

Complete working example:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.*;

import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

class OverrideSXSSFWorkbook {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (
   SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new MySXSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   Row row;
   Cell cell;

   row = sheet.createRow(0);
   cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("CellValue");
 
   workbook.write(fileout);
   workbook.close();
   workbook.dispose();

  }
 }
}

class MySXSSFWorkbook extends SXSSFWorkbook {

 @Override
 protected SheetDataWriter createSheetDataWriter() throws IOException {

  if(isCompressTempFiles()) {
   System.out.println("GZIPSheetDataWriter");
   //return new GZIPSheetDataWriter(getSharedStringSource());

   return new GZIPSheetDataWriter(getSharedStringSource()) {

    @Override
    protected InputStream decorateInputStream(FileInputStream fis) throws IOException {
     System.out.println("overridden decorateInputStream");
     return new GZIPInputStream(fis);
    }
   };

  }
  System.out.println("default SheetDataWriter");
  return new SheetDataWriter(getSharedStringSource());

 }
}
```

Comment: so nice of you. It's a basic java question indeed, blame myself not read poi code carefully.